# Is it possible to edit the 'field' class variable in Django CBV using URL args?

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to use a CreateView to create a profile object. Depending on the type of profile, though, I want to show a different set of fields. Right now I am passing the type of profile through the url.

How would I go about accessing this argument to filter the types of fields? I know how to do so in something like a get() function in a CBV, but not in the body of the class itself. I also do not know if there is an appropriate function to do this in and have not been able to find a solution in the docs.

Thank you in advance for any help, and I am sorry if this question has an obvious answer that I have missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to override some method. Potential methods that can work are `get_form_class`, `get_form`, etc. Try overriding `get_form`:

```
class MyView(CreateView):
    model = SomeModel
    fields = None
    
    def get_form(self):
        self.fields = ['field1', 'field2'] # set this according to your conditions
        # the keyword arguments passed to the view can be accessed by using self.kwargs.get('<key_name>')
        return super().get_form()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.